# How to put timer in guessing game in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm having a problem with my Javascript code that involves putting a timer in a Random guessing game. I must give the user 5 seconds to guess the number. The user can guess multiple times within the span of 5 seconds. If the time runs out, I must prompt the user if he wants to play again or exit. If yes I have to loop back to the game. My timer is not working. I would every much appreciate it if any of you guys can help. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var randomNumber = getRandomNumber(6); 
    var userGuess; 
    var guessCounter = 0 

    function timer (upper) {
        var timeID = setInterval (getRandomNumber, 5000);
    }

    function getRandomNumber (upper) {
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*upper) +1; 
        return number;
    }
    while (userGuess != randomNumber){
        userGuess = prompt('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 6. \n What is it? '); 
        guessCounter += 1; 

        if (parseInt(userGuess) > randomNumber) {
            alert('Try again! Your number is too high ' );
        }else if (parseInt(userGuess) < randomNumber) {
            alert('Try again! Your number is too low ');
        }else if(parseInt(userGuess) == randomNumber) {
            break;
        }
    }
    alert('You have guessed the number! It took you: \n ' +  guessCounter +  ' tries. '); 
</script>
```

Comment: Your code flow is wrong. There isn't anything calling your timer method so the setInterval never starts. You'll want to generate a random number at the start, begin the user loop and have a timer going that after 5 seconds calls a method that shows the game over prompt.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when your timer is not working ? You are just passing getRandomNumber to setInterval. you should try something like this. setInterval(function() { getRandomNumber(6) }, 5000). Also, you need to call timer to actually get it started. You are not doing  that anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `prompt` freezes the internal timer (in  Chrome, Opera and Safari), we can't set a timeout for the user's response. One way is to use html `<input>` instead of `prompt`. In this case `setTimeout` works as desired.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const getRandomNumber = (upper) => Math.floor(Math.random() * upper) + 1;
const upper = 10;
let guessCounter = 0;
let randomNumber = getRandomNumber(upper);
let timer;

const play = () => {
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    input.value = "";
    guessCounter++;
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (confirm("Time is out. Play again?")) {
            randomNumber = getRandomNumber(upper);
            guessCounter = 0;
            play();
        }
    }, 5000);
}

document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = `I am thinking of a number between 1 and ${upper}. What is it?`;

document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let userGuess = parseInt(input.value); 
    if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
        alert('Try again! Your number is too high');
        play();
    } else if (userGuess < randomNumber) {
        alert('Try again! Your number is too low ');
        play();
    } else if (userGuess === randomNumber) {
        if (confirm(`You have guessed the number! It took you: ${guessCounter} tries. Play again?`)) {
            randomNumber = getRandomNumber(upper);
            guessCounter = 0;
            play();
        } else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }
});

play();
```

```html
<div id="question"></div>
<input id="input" type="input">
<button id="guess">Guess</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving your game into a function and naming it, e.g. "startGame". Then, when the game finishes it, you can implement your timer to relaunch the game.

```js
function getRandomNumber(upper) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*upper) + 1; 
    return number;
}

function startGame() {
    var randomNumber = getRandomNumber(6); 
    var userGuess; 
    var guessCounter = 0;
    var playAgain;
    
    while (userGuess != randomNumber){
        userGuess = prompt('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 6. \n What is it? '); 
        guessCounter += 1; 

        if (parseInt(userGuess) > randomNumber) {
            alert('Try again! Your number is too high ' );
        } else if (parseInt(userGuess) < randomNumber) {
            alert('Try again! Your number is too low ');
        } else if (parseInt(userGuess) == randomNumber) {
            break;
        }
    }
    alert('You have guessed the number! It took you: \n ' +  guessCounter +  ' tries. '); 
    
    if (confirm('Do you want to play again?')) {
        setInterval(startGame, 5000); // Start a new game in 5 seconds
    }
}

startGame();
```